# How to join to tables in order to be able to calculate time difference

Tags: sql, generics, powerbi

My initial table looks as follows:

[initial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Ooo.png)

There I want to calculate the time difference between login and logout. Therefor I want to create two new tables. One table which contains only logins and the 2nd table only contains logouts:

[login-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE6X6.png)

[logout-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqbrB.png)

My idea is now to do in a next step a join to merge these tables in order to be able to create a column with time difference:

[joined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUBTh.png)

The problem is:
-the blue colored rows are no problem. They can be identified by unique values (System = 2-system;  or day = 2)

-But how can I assign the correct logout time for user john, who does a login twice a day (day 1) and also a logout twice a day?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you but here is an idea.

1. Add new column in logout table ex: SessionLength (how long from login till logout).
2. Get the last login from the login table when he tries to logout and just substract the time of logout - when he logged in and just save in SessionLength column. Hope this idea can help